# Is sys.stats_columns incorrect?

Tags: sql-server, statistics

Let's say I have a table `Foo` with columns `ID1, ID2` and a composite primary key defined over `ID2, ID1`. (I'm currently working with a System Center product that has several tables defined this way with the primary key columns listed in the opposite order they appear in the table definition.)

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Foo(
  ID1 int NOT NULL,
  ID2 int NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_Foo] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (ID2, ID1)
);
GO

-- Add a row and update stats so that histogram isn't empty
INSERT INTO Foo (ID1, ID2) VALUES (1,2);
UPDATE STATISTICS dbo.Foo;
```

The `key_ordinal` column in `sys.index_columns` shows the index columns in the same order they were declared in the composite primary key:

```
SELECT t.name, i.name, c.column_id, c.name, ic.index_column_id, ic.key_ordinal
FROM sys.tables AS t
JOIN sys.indexes AS i
ON t.[object_id] = i.[object_id]
JOIN sys.index_columns AS ic
ON ic.[object_id] = i.[object_id]
AND ic.index_id = i.index_id
JOIN sys.columns AS c
ON ic.column_id = c.column_id
AND ic.[object_id] = c.[object_id]
WHERE t.name = 'Foo';
```

[image: index]

The histogram also shows the statistics in the same order:

```
DBCC SHOW_STATISTICS ('Foo',PK_Foo);
```

[image: stats]

However, `sys.stats_columns` shows the columns listed in the inverse order (`ID1, ID2`).

```
SELECT s.name, sc.stats_column_id, c.name
FROM sys.stats AS s
JOIN sys.stats_columns AS sc 
ON s.stats_id = sc.stats_id 
AND s.[object_id] = sc.[object_id] 
JOIN sys.columns AS c 
ON c.[object_id] = s.[object_id]
AND c.column_id = sc.column_id
JOIN sys.objects AS o 
ON o.[object_id] = c.[object_id] 
WHERE o.name = 'Foo'
AND s.name = 'PK_Foo';
```

[image: stats_columns]

[Books Online](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187340.aspx) says `stats_column_id` is a "1-based ordinal within set of stats columns," so I was expecting the value 1 to point to the first column in the statistics object.

Is this a bug in `sys.stats_columns` or a misunderstanding on my part?

I've verified this behaviour occurs on current builds of SQL Server 2005, 2008, 2008 R2, 2012, and 2014.

`sys.stats_columns` seems to reflect the order within the statistics object in other situations, for example:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Foo2(
  ID1 int NOT NULL,
  ID2 int NOT NULL,
  ID3 int NULL,
  String VARCHAR(10) NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_Foo2] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (ID2, ID1)
);

GO

INSERT INTO Foo2 (ID1, ID2, ID3, String) VALUES (1,2,3,'String');

CREATE STATISTICS ST_Test ON Foo2 (ID3, String);
CREATE STATISTICS ST_Test2 ON Foo2 (String, ID3);

DBCC SHOW_STATISTICS ('Foo2',ST_Test);
DBCC SHOW_STATISTICS ('Foo2',ST_Test2);


SELECT s.name, sc.stats_column_id, c.name
FROM sys.stats AS s
JOIN sys.stats_columns AS sc 
ON s.stats_id = sc.stats_id 
AND s.[object_id] = sc.[object_id] 
JOIN sys.columns AS c 
ON c.[object_id] = s.[object_id]
AND c.column_id = sc.column_id
JOIN sys.objects AS o 
ON o.[object_id] = c.[object_id] 
WHERE o.name = 'Foo2'
AND s.name LIKE 'ST_Test%';
```

[image: morestats]

Here is another example where `sys.stats_columns` appears to return the correct data, this time for statistics on an index:

```
--drop table dbo.Foo3
CREATE TABLE dbo.Foo3(
  ID1 int NOT NULL,
  ID2 int NOT NULL,
  ID3 int NULL,
  String VARCHAR(10) NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_Foo3] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (ID2, ID1)
);

GO

INSERT INTO Foo3 (ID1, ID2, ID3, String) VALUES (1,2,3,'String');
UPDATE STATISTICS Foo3;

CREATE INDEX IX_Test ON Foo3 (ID3, String);
CREATE INDEX IX_Test2 ON Foo3 (String, ID3);

DBCC SHOW_STATISTICS ('Foo3',IX_Test);
DBCC SHOW_STATISTICS ('Foo3',IX_Test2);

SELECT s.name, sc.stats_column_id, c.name
FROM sys.stats AS s
JOIN sys.stats_columns AS sc 
ON s.stats_id = sc.stats_id 
AND s.[object_id] = sc.[object_id] 
JOIN sys.columns AS c 
ON c.[object_id] = s.[object_id]
AND c.column_id = sc.column_id
JOIN sys.objects AS o 
ON o.[object_id] = c.[object_id] 
WHERE o.name = 'Foo3'
AND s.name LIKE 'IX_Test%';
```

[image: moremorestats]

Comment: I had the same question a few months ago but deleted it. Sorry about that. Nonetheless, the `stats_column_id` in `sys.stats_columns` doesn't seem to do what it says it does. Because you're backing an index, I'd stick with the index column order. If you're just looking at stats objects it looks like `index_col()` is the best option currently

Comment: Perhaps you should/could file a Microsoft Connect item for this?  Seems buggy to me.

Comment: @MaxVernon, swashesk has filed one [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/1163126)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems to be a long standing error:

swasheck - March 5, 2015 posted:

https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/1163126

> MSDN notes that sys.stats_columns.stats_column_id is "1-based ordinal
> within set of stats columns." However, it seems to actually reflect
> table definition order. Altering index order is not reflected in
> sys.stats_columns.

Hannah Vernon and James Lupolt seem to agree based on their comments/encouragement.

Comment: The Database Docs team is looking into this.